# None of + a singular noun

Tags: grammar

Example:

> Q: Is any of the vegetable fresh?
>   A: No, none of it is fresh.

Can we use `none of` with a singular noun?

Comment: It doesn't sound right; I think it should be "Are any of the vegetables fresh?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: Is any of the vegetable fresh?
>   A: No, none of it is fresh.

As it stands, this question and answer are grammatically correct but probably not what you mean. **the vegetable** is singular, so we are talking about one vegetable- say a carrot. The question asks whether any part of the carrot is fresh: the answer is that no part of the carrot is fresh.

This could be used with humorous intent, for example like the story of [the parson's egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curate%27s_egg), but is unlikely to be asked as a serious question.

What you probably meant was:

> Q: Are any of the vegetables fresh?
>   A: No, none of them are fresh.

We are now talking about a number of vegetables: maybe some carrots, some onions and also a few tomatoes. The question asks whether any of these vegetables are fresh, and the answer is that none of them are fresh.

The answer to your question is: yes, you can use none of with a singular noun, but what it means is **no part of**. It only really works if the one item is divisible into parts. This is always possible with uncountable nouns, for example sugar, but could also be true of something that is countable, for example a book:

> Q: How much of this book have you read?
>   A: I have read none of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please see [Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/none_1), where it says: "_none of can be followed by a plural noun or an uncountable noun_".

Comment: @Mori, I take back my comment about the egg: the countability isn't really the point. I have updated my answer to explain circumstances in which **none of** can be used for countable singular nouns, as long as they are **divisible**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'none of' before a plural noun, singular noun, or uncountable noun.  When you use it before a singular or uncountable noun, it means "not any amount or part of it", and the verb we should use is singular.

vegetable is a singular noun; we are talking about a specific vegetable. So we must say:

None of it is fresh.

However, in case of a plural noun, vegetables, you can use either a plural verb or a singular verb as follows:

None of the vegetables are/is fresh.

But we usually use a plural verb; the use of a singular verb is formal.